# Is $e^{\alpha\log(M)}$ equal to $M^{\alpha}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, logarithms

Supposing the matrix logarithm exists, is $e^{\alpha\log(M)}$ equal to $M^{\alpha}?$

This equality obviously holds for positive reals, but does it also hold for matrices?

Comment: Yes. $      \,\,\,\,   $

Comment: How do you define $M^\alpha$ when $\alpha$ is not an integer?

Comment: @mrf : maybe this way? ;-)

Comment: Well, if that's your definition, the answer is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

This equality obviously does not hold for unless you choose a branch of the logarithm. Consider $2 \log(-1) \neq \log(1)$.

Comment: I've changed my question to remove my observation about "obviousness" :) I'm still interested in knowing if this hold true for any kind of matrices.

Comment: Yes, it does, if you choose a branch of the log. Otherwise, you are looking at sets of values, that may not coincide as in the example above.

Comment: This is the usual way of defining power of a matrix, where you have chosen a branch of the log already.

Comment: Take a look at the [Complex logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm)